# Python weighted random choices from lists with different probability, comparing two Pandas DataFrame from CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, random, probability, weighted

Python beginner, here. I am attempting to take a pandas DataFrame (created from a CSV) and use weighted random choices to choose from another DataFrame (created from a CSV). What I have is two pandas DataFrames that read something like this:

**Weighted Percentages of codes:**

| SECTION | CODE | Final_Per |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | 800 | 5% |
| B1 | 801 | 65% |
| B1 | 802 | 30% |
| B2 | 900 | 30% |
| B2 | 901 | 70% |
| B3 | 600 | 50% |
| B3 | 601 | 50% |

**Input pandas DataFrame to run weighted percentages on:**

| SECTION | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 14 |
| B2 | 25 |
| B3 | 12 |

These are just examples of my tables rather than the entirety of the tables themselves. What I need to do is store these weighted probabilities whether in a dictionary, lists, or pandas dataframes (not sure what's best) - and take my second table above and apply the 'Final_Per' %'s to the 'NUMBER' column and output the result. So B1's result would be 14 values, 5% being code 800, 65% being code 801, and 30% being code 802. Currently, the tables are CSV's and I am turning them into pandas dataframes and attempting to take some lessons learned from this article https://pynative.com/python-weighted-random-choices-with-probability/ to no success. Does anybody have suggestions on how to handle this correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it is to load the csv files into dataframes, merge them and use `.apply`.

```py
from numpy.random import choice

df1 = pd.read_csv(/path/to/csv1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(/path/to/csv2)

def calculate_distribution(mini_df): 
    prob = mini_df.Final_Per.str[:-1].astype(float) / 100
    return choice(mini_df.CODE.values, mini_df.NUMBER.values[0], p=prob)

distributions = df1.merge(df2, on='SECTION').groupby('SECTION').apply(calculate_distribution)
print(distributions)
```

Comment: tried your solution. I'm receiving an error here: **AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'** referring to `prob = mini_df.prob.str[:-1].astype(float) / 100`

Comment: I just realized I was using different column names, sorry. I updated the code to match the names in your example. Does it work now?

Comment: yes! This is a great solution to my problem. Thank you for the help and clarification

Comment: Is there an effective way that you see to export this output to a CSV by transposing the rows and also keeping the SECTION column intact? I am attempting to export but am losing the SECTION column and also the lists are being placed into separate columns with this: `with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(distributions)`

Answer (score 0):

If you reshape the CSV data into something like:

```
SECTION_COUNTS = {
    "B1": 14,
    "B2": 25,
    "B3": 12,
}

SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS = {
    "B1": [
        {"code": 800, "from": 1, "to": 5},
        {"code": 801, "from": 6, "to": 70},
        {"code": 802, "from": 71, "to": 100}
    ],
    "B2": [
        {"code": 900, "from": 1, "to": 70},
        {"code": 901, "from": 71, "to": 100}
    ],
    "B3": [
        {"code": 600, "from": 1, "to": 50},
        {"code": 601, "from": 51, "to": 100}
    ]
}
```

The I think the answer you seek might be given by:

```py
import random

results = {}
for section_id, count in SECTION_COUNTS.items():
    for _ in range(count):
        code = next(
            row["code"]
            for row
            in SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS[section_id]
            if row["from"] <= random.randint(1, 100) <= row["to"]
        )
        results.setdefault(section_id, []).append(code)
print(results)
```

Resulting in something like:

```
{
    'B1': [801, 801, 802, 801, 801, 802, 800, 802, 802, 801, 802, 801, 800, 801],
    'B2': [900, 900, 900, 900, 900, 901, 900, 900, 901, 900, 900, 901, 901, 900, 900, 900, 901, 900, 901, 900, 900, 901, 900, 901, 900],
    'B3': [601, 601, 600, 600, 600, 601, 601, 601, 600, 601, 600, 600]
}
```

**Addendum:**

It was ask how one might go about reshaping a CSV like:

```
SECTION,CODE,Final_Per
B1,800,5
B1,801,65
B1,802,30
B2,900,30
B2,901,70
B3,600,50
B3,601,50
```

into our `SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS`. Let's take a look at that. The way I would initially tackle this would be to keep track on some information from the prior row of our csv as we iterate through the rows

```py
import csv
import json

with open("in.csv", "r") as file_in:
    SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS = {}
    prior_to = 0
    prior_section = ""

    for current_row in csv.DictReader(file_in):
        curr_section = current_row["SECTION"]

        if prior_section != curr_section:
            prior_section = curr_section
            prior_to = 0

        curr_code = current_row["CODE"]
        curr_from = prior_to + 1
        curr_to = prior_to + int(current_row["Final_Per"])

        target = SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS.setdefault(curr_section, [])
        target.append({"code": curr_code, "from": curr_from, "to": curr_to})
        prior_to = curr_to

    print(json.dumps(SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS, indent=4))
```

That should result in:

```
{
    "B1": [
        {
            "code": "800",
            "from": 1,
            "to": 5
        },
        {
            "code": "801",
            "from": 6,
            "to": 70
        },
        {
            "code": "802",
            "from": 71,
            "to": 100
        }
    ],
    "B2": [
        {
            "code": "900",
            "from": 1,
            "to": 30
        },
        {
            "code": "901",
            "from": 31,
            "to": 100
        }
    ],
    "B3": [
        {
            "code": "600",
            "from": 1,
            "to": 50
        },
        {
            "code": "601",
            "from": 51,
            "to": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a suggestion on how to convert the syntax of the SECTION_DISTRIBUTIONS dictionary? So going from percentages to something like you have, "from": 1, "to": 5 for example. I understand how to convert to a dictionary, but breaking up the column row text in this way confuses me.